# Word that describes "Giving importance more to the person rather than to his ideals"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Idolization, Personality craze - Doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'm not sure if maybe fanboyism would apply, because most fanboys/fangirls seem to ignore, for example, music of the artist that they are obsessing about, and just squeal at his abs/her boobs.

Answer (score 3):

It guess you are referring to:

[Cult of personality](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_of_personality):

> Cult of personality arises when an individual uses mass media, propaganda, or other methods, to create an idealized, heroic, and at times, worshipful image, often through unquestioning flattery and praise.
>
> - Sociologist Max Weber developed a tripartite classification of authority; the cult of personality holds parallels with what Weber defined as "charismatic authority". A cult of personality is similar to hero worship, except that it is established by mass media and propaganda usually by the state, especially in totalitarian states.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather say  [adulation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adulation): extreme admiration; excessive devotion to someone